# Trouble with Rails 3 has_many :through association and views/forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have previously used has_and_belongs_to_many associations in my older Rails apps but am moving to using has_many, :through for new and current apps. However, I believe I am missing something central to the has_many, :through association in Rails 3.

Currently, I am building an app for our town's volunteer fire department. When we have a meeting, we want to check off whether or not a fire fighter is present, excused, or absent.

My models:

```
#FireFighter Model
class FireFighter < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :attendance_meetings
has_many :meetings, :through => :attendance_meetings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :meeting

#Meeting Model
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :attendance_meetings
has_many :fire_fighters, :through => :attendance_meetings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fire_fighter

#AttendanceMeeting Model
class AttendanceMeeting < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :status # this is the added property on the join model that we need populated
belongs_to :fire_fighter
belongs_to :meeting
```

The problem I'm having is how to set this up in the view. Currently, I have:

```
= hidden_field_tag "meeting[fire_fighter_ids][]"
-@meeting.fire_fighters.each do |fire_fighter|
  = fire_fighter.fire_fighter_name 
  %span.radio_btn= radio_button_tag :fire_figher_ids, fire_fighter.id, "present"
  present
  %span.radio_btn= radio_button_tag :fire_figher_ids, fire_fighter.id, "excused"
  excused
  %span.radio_btn= radio_button_tag :fire_figher_ids, fire_fighter.id, "absent"
  absent
  %br
```

This will spit out each fire fighter and three radio buttons for each fire fighter (with options for present, excused, or absent). However, the name of the resulting radio buttons are all the same, so you can only pick one for all fire fighters.

As I noted above, I feel certain I am missing something basic but I am stumped. I've read through tons of SO questions and The Rails 3 Way book's sections on ActiveRecord. Any suggestions or directions would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendance_meetings
  has_many :fire_fighters, :through => :attendance_meetings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendance_meetings

# view
= form_for @meeting do |f|
  = f.fields_for :attendance_meetings do |f_a_m|
    = f_a_m.object.fire_fighter.name
    = f_a_m.check_box :status, 'present'
    = f_a_m.check_box :status, 'excused'
    = f_a_m.check_box :status, 'absent'
```

For the approach you're taking you need to build the association for each firefighter with the meeting. Something like:

```
@meeting.firefighters << Firefighter.all
```

This doesn't seem particularly optimal however. I would form the join with a boolean :status for those who are absent (t) or excused (f) with present not included, imagine it like meeting_absentees. Seems backward but in this way your table will have far fewer rows.

Comment: thanks! I appreciate the response and am trying out this approach now. I kept thinking I was going at the wrong association in the form (fire_fighters v. attendance_meeting).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me but, I believe, I have something amiss in my Models.

Comment: Thanks, again, Mark. The main issue I ran into is that, while in the fields_for iteration, it would error on = f_a_m.object.fire_fighter.xxx (no method found for fire_fighter). Basically, it did not see an object. If I tried to output the object (f_a_m.object.to_s or using a breakpoint while debugging), nothing would show. I ended up coming up with a workaround in the form view and meetings controller but still feel as though I'm missing something central to managing has_many :through relationships. No biggie, though ... just more reading to do :)

Comment: Sorry but I included an error in my answer; the fields_for should be many (plural) attendance_meetings. Check edit.

Comment: I tried the plural (:attendance_meetings) yesterday but did not implement it correctly as I never initialized the attendance_meetings association. Now, however, that code does output checkboxes but it only outputs them once because there is only one attendance_meeting object in that has_many association. It also fails to see the fire_fighter property (f_a_m.object.attendance_meeting.fire_fighter_id, however, does work). I do think I have something amiss in my models or this would work properly! Cheers! Craig

Comment: You will need to build the association for each meeting and each firefighter. I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Got it rolling well now, Mark. Thanks, again and apologies for forget ting to note that yours was the answer ... fixed that error this morning :).